# Can you transfer Batman Arkham City saves from PS3 to Steam?

Tags: steam, ps3, batman-arkham-city

When Batman Arkham City first came out, I bought it for PS3 and beat the game while finishing a few extra side missions. Since then, I've gotten rid of my PS3 copy and got a steam version. I still have the saved file on my PS3. I wanted to know if I could somehow transfer my game saves from my PS3 to my steam account?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but good luck finding an answer that proves me wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PS3 save files are stored in a proprietary format which is not designed to be handled or integrated by any other software than Sony's own software. This makes all of the PS3 save files unusable by any other system.

Any software can potentially be reverse engineered to fit another system than what was originally intended, but this would also mean breaking a host of copyright laws.

If there exists a third party software that opens up the PS3 save files, I don't know of it, but it would definitely not be legal.

Comment: Umm, not exactly. It's true that the save files are proprietary, it's not true they're always non-transferable. One example would be cross-save games that allow progress to transfer between PS3/PS4/Vita via cloud sync. Another example is Portal 2 which shares it's progress with the Steam version via Steam Cloud Saves.

Comment: What you're saying is technically true, but the PS3/PS4/Vita argument is still within the Sony ecosystem.
As for Portal 2, you still can't take the PS3 save files and push them to Steam. This is done using their own service, which too few games to mention supports.